# Reduce Space Between y-axis Tick Labels

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am making a data visualization for a metrics dashboard which shows how much we are releasing over time.

I've got a bubble plot that has

- year on the y-axis
- month on the x-axis
- where bubble diameter represents the number of releases in that month

I am trying to make the data visualization more interesting. I have plans to add a color scale, but I have a problem where there is a ton of space between 2019 and 2018 that I want to fix first.

That said, I am also open to other suggestions :)

Here's what I've got currently: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzZ8j.jpg

I basically want to squash the **on the y-axis** space between 2019 and 2018, and 2017 and 2018.

Here's what my data looks like

```
   year     month releases_per_month
0   2017    9      10
1   2017    10     10
2   2017    11     9
3   2017    12     15
4   2018    1      14
```

Here's the code that creates my scatter plot

```
plt.figure(figsize = (12,7.5))

plt.scatter(x=df_gby['month'], 
            y=df_gby['year'], 
            s=df_gby['releases_per_month'] * 100,)

plt.xticks(np.arange(13), [' ', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']);
plt.yticks([2017, 2018, 2019])
plt.title('Releases by Month by Year', fontsize = 16)
plt.xlabel('Month', fontsize = 16)
plt.ylabel('Year', fontsize = 16)
plt.xticks(fontsize = 14)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 14);
```

Comment: Try `plt.margins(y=0.3)` or whatever number suits your needs.